# Setting 2D Char Array to Null in C, but Still Getting Char values?

Tags: arrays, c, char

Essentially, I am trying to created a method in C that takes a sentence input from the user in the form of a char array, and returns each word on its own separate line as well as the total number of words in the sentence. For example, if the user inputs "Hi My Name is Fred". Then, the output should be each word on its own line followed by "Total Number of words: 5". It seems simple enough to code, and it was except for one detail I simply cannot understand. When the total number of words is not 5(the maximum), I get a bunch of random garbage chars even though I have already set the default to '\0'. Here's the code:

```
int splitAndPrintWords(char s[NUM_STRINGS*STRING_LENGTH]) //NUMSTRINGS is 5 while STRING_LENGTH is 50.
{
    char str[NUM_STRINGS][STRING_LENGTH]; //An array for storing the sentence word by word 
                                          //The first word would be in str[0], the second in str[1], etc.
    
    int count = 0;                                               
    for(int k = 0; k < NUM_STRINGS; k++)          // Here I loop through the 2D array of chars to set 
    {                                             // them all to '\0' values, so they aren't printed.
        for(int p = 0; p < STRING_LENGTH; p++)
        {
            str[k][p] = '\0';
        }
    }

    int k = 0;
    int p = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS*STRING_LENGTH; i++)  //this loop is for putting each word from the  
    {                                                   //sentence into the new 2d array. 
        if(s[i] != ' ')                                 //I use ' ' as the delimiter between words. 
        {
            str[k][p] = s[i];
            p++; 
        }
        else
        {
            k++;
            p = 0;
        }
    }
    count = k+1;
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS; i++)        //lastly I print each word on it's own line, as intended
    {
        printf("%s\n", str[i]);
    }
    

    return count;                             //returns count so the main method can print how many 
}                                             // words are in the sentence.
```

***The output results in the following:***

Enter words (max 5): Why
Why

ùw%Γd±■   t■a

Number of words= 1

***Another example would be***

Enter words (max 5): This is Three
This
is
Three

t■a

Number of words= 3

***How do I get rid of the garbage chars?***

Comment: You're not stopping when you get to the null terminator of the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the copying loop when you get to the null terminator of `s`. Otherwise, you're copying the garbage characters after the terminator into `str`.

```
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STRINGS*STRING_LENGTH && s[i] != '\0'; i++)  //this loop is for putting each word from the  
    {                                                   //sentence into the new 2d array. 
        if(s[i] != ' ')                                 //I use ' ' as the delimiter between words. 
        {
            str[k][p] = s[i];
            p++; 
        }
        else
        {
            k++;
            p = 0;
        }
    }
```